# awsのdocker login上の問題

Tags: aws, docker

弊社では、クラウド環境はawsを使用しています。
そこで、ECRのdocker機能を利用しています。
さて、今回次のコマンドでdocker loginした後、docker buildでエラーを生じました。

```
pip install awscli --upgrade --user
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email
docker login -u AWS -p ********   == https://01234.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com


docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  52.76MBStep 1/5 : FROM 56789.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:latestGet https://56789.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com: no basic auth credentials
```

確かに"01234"と"56789"が異なっています。
FROMが異なる場合、どうしたらよろしいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

実は、"01234"と"56789"を入れ替えてdocker loginしました。
ところが、次のエラーメッセージが表示されました。

```
FROM 56789.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com:latestpull access denied for 56789.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

この問題、一体全体何が悪いのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://01234.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com

このURLのサブドメイン、 `01234` はAWSのアカウントIDを示しています。

> **aws_account_id**.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-world
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-basics.html

そのため、

- ご自身のアカウントIDが `01234` で、そちらにベースとなるDockerイメージが存在するなら、DockerfileにおけるFROMの参照を `01234` に書き換える
- `56789` のアカウントにしかベースとなるDockerイメージが存在しないなら、 `56789` のアカウントを利用してログインする

という方法で解決するかと存じます。

Comment: 本件、いろいろ試してみたところ、前任者の環境（FROM の行）に変更したらbuildが成功しました。ご協力ありがとうございました。